# Select columns of dataframe filling with NA's in selected column doesn't exist

Tags: r, select, dataframe, subset, na

Take this example data frame

```
temp <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 'b' = 4:6, 'd' = 7:9)
```

I want to subset this data frame using a vector of column names, but if the vector contains any columns that don't exist in the data frame I want them still to be returned but as NA.

So if my vector was

```
colVec <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
```

I would want to run something along the lines of

```
subset(temp, select = colVec)
```

to get

```
a b c
1 4 NA
2 5 NA
3 6 NA
```

Comment: Just do `temp[,colVec[colVec %in% names(temp)]]` and if you really want to add `NA` columns (**why?**) then use `!` to append `NA` with the absent column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in two steps -- limiting to the requested columns that are in your data frame and then adding the requested columns that are not in your data frame. You can use `intersect` and `setdiff` to get these two sets of column names:

```
temp2 <- temp[intersect(colVec, names(temp))]
temp2[setdiff(colVec, names(temp))] <- NA
temp2
#   a b  c
# 1 1 4 NA
# 2 2 5 NA
# 3 3 6 NA
```